# There comes white box with image button only in iPhone browser

Tags: html, css

I have button.

```
<div class="row" id="ctrlBar">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="text-center">
      <img type="button" class="ctrlBtn" src="img/NextTry.png" onMouseOut="this.src='img/NextTry.png'" onMouseOver="this.src='img/NextTry_hover.png'" id="nextBtn"/>
      </div>
</div>
```

in Style sheet

```
.ctrlBtn{
  height:50px;
  max-width:300px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .ctrlBtn{
    height:32px;
    width:252px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px ;
  }
```

It looks well for browser on PC and android.

However on iPhone it looks like this with white transparent box.

[image]

Image file is

[image]

`650 x 129`

Why does this happen??

Comment: `<img type="button"` is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make button outside of `img` tag . because `<img type="button"` is not valid HTML.

```
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="text-center">
      <button id="nextBtn">
         <img class="ctrlBtn" src="img/NextTry.png" onMouseOut="this.src='img/NextTry.png'" onMouseOver="this.src='img/NextTry_hover.png'" />
      </button>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you somehow img type button worked though, your answer  clears the white box!!